# Оптимизация схему БД для FULLTEXT индекса

Tags: mysql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Как получить оптимальную схему для работы MySQL БД с таблицей в которой присутствует FULLTEXT индекс поля VARCHAR(255).

Каждый день в таблицу добавляется 200 000 строк и запрос должен всегда использовать полнотекстовый поиск по этому FULLTEXT индексу.

В самой таблице и этих данных ограничений по времени нет - в запросе нужно просматривать все данные из этого поля, всегда.

Когда в таблице 3-4 млн записей, уже к этому моменту запрос MATCH ... AGAINST вызывает 100% нагрузку CPU достаточно современного сервера, пока не получит результат запроса.

И даже не могу предположить, в каком направлении двигаться, чтобы уменьшить нагрузку на CPU в поиске этой информации в этой таблице.

Если кто-нибудь в курсе, как и что можно изменить, посоветуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: Переходите на внешний поисковый движок.

Comment: Чем это исправит нагрузку на CPU? Это только увеличит её на 30% в среднем.